# Help me check my understanding of functions and composite functions!

Tags: functions

I have the following questions and understanding regarding functions and composite functions. Am i right? :)

Understanding:

 1) We define function as one which assigns each element in a set to a unique element in another set. (Passes vertical line test)

 2) If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions, and range of $f(x)$ is a subset of domain of $g(x)$, composite function  $(g \circ f)(x)$  exists.

Questions: 

 Q1) Must $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be functions for understanding 2 to be  **always**  true?

 Q2) Is there a difference between saying: "$(g \circ f)(x)$  exists " and 

 "Composite function  $(g \circ f)(x)$  exists." ? 

 Q3) If  either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ is not a function, can we be certain to say if $(g \circ f)(x)$  is/is not a function and if $(g \circ f)(x)$  exists/do not exists?

Comment: Re Q3: How is $g\circ f$ defined if $f$ or $g$ is not a function? Are you talking about relations and theri composition?

Comment: Re Q3: Composition is well-defined more generally for binary relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just necessary correct you in the point: by definition, the composition is between **functions**, so.. doesnt make sense question yourself about it.

Indeed, there are concidences. For instance $f(x) = \pm x$ and $g(x) = x^2$. We almost say that $(g \circ f)(x)$ is function, but it not make sense, since $f$ is not a function. The confusion comes from $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$ result in the same composition. This give an example for Wuestenfux's comment.